# Using only one channel of 3-phase SSR

Tags: solid-state-relay

Is it possible to use 3-phase SSR for driving a single phase heater? The other two channels would be simply not connected. Is this going yo work as a single phase SSR?
The particular model of the SSR is LIRRD LRSSR-3DA.

Comment: Model of the SSR?

Comment: I see no reasons why the other two phases would care.

Comment: I also see no reason but only to be sure.

Comment: A 3-phase SSR used to control a three phase heater should not be destroyed if one or two circuit breakers open.